# I need to cast an object to string then retrieve it by casting it back to my object

Tags: java, string, hibernate, casting, tostring

I need to learn how to create my custom .tostring and .fromstring

I have tried casting it back to the object but it does not seem to be working
I have also tried to retrieve the object and converting it to string then comparing the strings but it still does not work

the issue began here so the .toString() was trying to bypass the issue

I could only save the elements id but it would be hectic during retrieval while dealing with three different tables at the same time

I would like a single persist to save the all the objects which I can achieve through that but would have to create three queries during retrieval unlike what I am currently doing with the Event entity

[detached entity passed to persist: entities.Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165768/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-entities-event)

```java
package entities;
// Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;




/**
 * Event generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Event  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String image;
     private String location;
     private int upto100;
     private Integer upto300;
     private Integer upto500;
     private Integer upto1000;
     private int phoneno;
     private String scenario;
     private String name;
     private String mail;
     private Users owner;
     private String description;

    public Event() {
    }


    public Event(String image, String location, int upto100, int phoneno, String scenario, String name, String mail) {
        this.image = image;
        this.location = location;
        this.upto100 = upto100;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
        this.scenario = scenario;
        this.name = name;
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    public Event(String image, String location, int upto100, Integer upto300, Integer upto500, Integer upto1000, int phoneno, String scenario, String name, String mail, Users owner, String description) {
       this.image = image;
       this.location = location;
       this.upto100 = upto100;
       this.upto300 = upto300;
       this.upto500 = upto500;
       this.upto1000 = upto1000;
       this.phoneno = phoneno;
       this.scenario = scenario;
       this.name = name;
       this.mail = mail;
       this.owner = owner;
       this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public int getUpto100() {
        return this.upto100;
    }

    public void setUpto100(int upto100) {
        this.upto100 = upto100;
    }
    public Integer getUpto300() {
        return this.upto300;
    }

    public void setUpto300(Integer upto300) {
        this.upto300 = upto300;
    }
    public Integer getUpto500() {
        return this.upto500;
    }

    public void setUpto500(Integer upto500) {
        this.upto500 = upto500;
    }
    public Integer getUpto1000() {
        return this.upto1000;
    }

    public void setUpto1000(Integer upto1000) {
        this.upto1000 = upto1000;
    }
    public int getPhoneno() {
        return this.phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }
    public String getScenario() {
        return this.scenario;
    }

    public void setScenario(String scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return this.mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    public Users getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Users owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /*public String toStreng(Event event) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(event);
    }

    public Event fromStreng(String string) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, Event.class);
    }*/


}
```

this is the class I need to overide the .tostring and .fromstring with
the page below is where I had to convert the object to string

```
<%-- 
    Document   : Book
    Created on : Jul 21, 2019, 8:27:27 PM
    Author     : Tariana
--%>

<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page import="entities.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
    String eventid = (String) session.getAttribute("venueid");
    Users owner = new Users();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(eventid);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Users.class)
        .configure();

    serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .build();        
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String hql = "SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.id = :id";
    Query query = sess.createQuery(hql);
    query.setInteger("id", id);
    List<Event> products;
    List results = query.list();
    products = results;

    Users own = null;
    Event venues = null;
    String upto;

    Iterator<Event> itr = products.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Event g = itr.next();
        System.out.println(g.getUpto100());
        owner = g.getOwner();
        own = owner;
        venues = g;
    }
    System.out.println(own.getUsername());
    String owns = (String) own.getUsername();
    sess.close();
    if(venues.getUpto300() != null){
        upto = "upto300";
    }else if(venues.getUpto500() != null){
        upto = "upto500";
    }else if(venues.getUpto1000() != null){
        upto = "upto1000";
    }else{
        upto = "upto100";
    }
    session.setAttribute("owner", owner);
    session.setAttribute("venue", venues);
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .navy{
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
        <%@include file = "BookHeader.jsp" %>
        <title>Book</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="lookbookHeader">
        <video autoplay poster="data:image/png;base64, <%=venues.getImage()%>" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.poster='event.png';" id="bgvid">

        </video>
        <div id="headerContentContainer">
            <h1 class="whitey"><%=venues.getName()%></h1>
            <div class="initial-arrow-small"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="introContent">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <br>
            <h2>Book Venue</h2>
            <h5 class="lefty">Email:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getMail()%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Max Capacity:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=upto%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Price for up to 100 people:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getUpto100()%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Price for up to 300 people:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getUpto300()%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Price for up to 500 people:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getUpto500() %></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Price for up to 1000 people:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getUpto1000()%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Phone no.:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getPhoneno()%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Location:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getLocation()%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Scenario:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=venues.getScenario()%></h5><br><br>
            <h5 class="lefty">Posted By:</h5> <h5 class="rightey"><%=owns%></h5><br><br>
            <p class="lefty">Description:</p> <p class="rightey">
                <%=venues.getDescription()%>
            </p><br><br>
            <h4>Set Event Details</h4>
            <form action="/Eventer/Booking">
                <!--<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
                <script>
                    $( "#from" ).datepicker().datepicker("setDate", "today");
                    $(function() {  
                        $( "#from" ).datepicker({   
                            defaultDate: "+0w",  
                            changeMonth: true,   
                            numberOfMonths: 1,
                            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {  
                              $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "today" );
                              $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                              $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                            }  
                        });  
                        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                            defaultDate: "today",
                            changeMonth: true,
                            numberOfMonths: 1,
                            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                              $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "today" );
                            }
                        });  
                    });  
                </script>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="eventedit">Start date:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="eventedit">End date:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="to" name = "to">
                </div>-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Event Name">Event Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eventname" id="" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="" required>
                    <small id="emailHelpId" class="form-text text-muted">Enter location of venue</small>
                </div>
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <label for="Event Name">Set Event Date:</label>
                    <input name="date" type='text' class="form-control" id="" aria-describedby="helpId" required/><br>
                    <small id="helpId" class="form-text text-muted">Enter date of event</small>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span><br>
                </div>
                    <script>
                        $(function () {
                            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                            var minDate = $( "#datetimepicker1" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
                            minDate.datepicker( "option", "minDate", "today" );
                        });
                      </script>
                      <h2>Choose Booking Capacity</h2>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="capacity" id="" checked value="upto100">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <br>   
                        <i class="fa fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"><h3>Up to 100 people</h3></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <%
                    if(venues.getUpto300() != null){
                        %>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="capacity" id="" value="upto300">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <br>   
                                <i class="fa fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"><h3>Up to 300 people</h3></i>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <%
                    }
                    %>
                <%
                    if(venues.getUpto500() != null){
                        %>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="capacity" id="" value="upto500">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <br>  
                                <i class="fa fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"><h3>Up to 500 people</h3></i>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <%
                    }
                    %>
                <%
                    if(venues.getUpto1000() != null){
                        %>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="capacity" id="" value="upto1000">
                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                <br>   
                                <i class="fa fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"><h3>Up to 1000 people</h3></i>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <%
                    }
                    %>
                <button class="btn-view">Book Venue</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to retrieve the items from the database in this page

```
<%-- 
    Document   : MyEvents
    Created on : Jul 23, 2019, 11:17:46 AM
    Author     : Tariana
--%>

<%@page import="entities.Event"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="newpackage.Booking"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Query"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.Session"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder"%>
<%@page import="entities.Users"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry"%>
<%@page import="org.hibernate.SessionFactory"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%
    //checks whether there is a farmer account with a session within the system
    //this header spans over all the pages after the farmer has logged into the system
    if(session.getAttribute("mail") == null){
            out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            out.println("alert('You need to login first!!');");
            out.println("window.location.href = \"/Eventer/Users/Login.jsp\";");
            out.println("</script>");
    }else{
        %>
        <html>
            <head>
                <%@include file="BookHeader.jsp" %>
                <title>My Events</title>
            </head>
            <body class="eventer">
                <div class="kadi">
            <%
                SessionFactory sessionFactory;
                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Users.class)
                    .configure();

                serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                        .build();        
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

                Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
                String hql = "FROM Booking";
                Query queryy = sess.createQuery(hql);
                List<Booking> buying;
                List results = queryy.list();
                buying = results;
                Iterator<Booking> itr = buying.iterator();
                Users owner;
                Event venue;
                Booking event = new Booking();
                System.out.println();

                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    Booking g = itr.next();
                    event = g;

                    %>

                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="event.png" alt="">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title"><%=event.getEventname()%></h4>
                                <p class="card-text">Date: <%=event.getDate()%></p>
                                <p class="card-text">Capacity for: <%=event.getCapacity()%></p>
                                <p class="card-text eve">ksh.<%=event.getPricing()%></p>
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="sr-only" for="inputName">Hidden input label</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="" value="" hidden>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn-view">View Venue</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <%
                }
            %>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        <%
    }
%>
```

booking class

```java
package newpackage;
// Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1



/**
 * Booking generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Booking  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String capacity;
     private String date;
     private String eventname;
     private String venue;
     private String owner;
     private int pricing;
     private String user;

    public Booking() {
    }

    public Booking(String capacity, String date, String eventname, String venue, String owner, int pricing, String user) {
       this.capacity = capacity;
       this.date = date;
       this.eventname = eventname;
       this.venue = venue;
       this.owner = owner;
       this.pricing = pricing;
       this.user = user;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCapacity() {
        return this.capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(String capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getEventname() {
        return this.eventname;
    }

    public void setEventname(String eventname) {
        this.eventname = eventname;
    }
    public String getVenue() {
        return this.venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(String venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }
    public String getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public int getPricing() {
        return this.pricing;
    }

    public void setPricing(int pricing) {
        this.pricing = pricing;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }




}
```

I need to learn a way to compare the objects or changing the object back to it's former object state

I want to try a .tostring method that converts each element to a string but it would raise an issue there I am storing classes for example the owner in the above POJO class which would cause the same issue that I am facing currently

Comment: What is the `fromstring` method?

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "but it still does not work" ... isnt a working problem description. You only posted your Event class, but *none* of your "testing" code that would instantiate an Event, call toString() on it, or fromstring() (whereever that method is implemented in the first place).

Comment: Beyond that: what is what you **actually** want to do? Turn an object into a specific string format (like JSON)? Or do you want to invent your own string format, and use that to (un)persist your Event objects?

Comment: here is where the issue began

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57165768/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-entities-event

Comment: so I instead converted all the mapping files to string and the class elements to string
in order for the persistence to work

Comment: let me share a bitbucket link to the whole project

Answer (score 1):

The process you are referring to is called Serialization, and is a large topic in programming. There are several libraries that can help you convert your class to a `String` and back.

One such library that I (and many people) have used extensively is Jackson, a json parsing library: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson
This library allows you to write the following code:

```
public static String toString(Event event) {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(event);
}

public static Event fromString(String string) {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, Event.class);
}
```

I also see your class implements `Serializable`. I would reccomend the above approach over using java inbuilt serialization, since there are several issues with java serialization. For example, if you change your class, the serialization fails without very special care.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the download link for the jar file

Comment: I am using serializable since I am using hibernate as my database and have created the mapper as well as the class directly from the database

Comment: green button on the link with the text "clone or download", or if you are using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle, the project is stored in Maven Central, for easy access.

Comment: the link does not link to the libraries I had to download all the 3 libraries from their site
but had the issue below while implementing the loc

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: entities.Event["owner"]->entities.Users_$$_jvstad2_1["handler"])

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish with this (especially the "comparing" part). *Why* do you want to convert the object to a String?

But in general what you want is not "casting" (i.e. treating the *unchanged* object as some other, compatible type) but "serialization" (i.e. converting the object into a storable format). I'd guess one of the many available JSON or XML serializers would do the trick - again depending on *why* you want to do this.

Have a look at [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [boon](https://github.com/boonproject/boon), [kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) for example libraries that might fit your needs.

Comment: I need to display the object elements on my website using <%=Users.location()%>
but I have stored it as a string