# detached entity passed to persist: entities.Event

Tags: xml, jpa, entity, hibernate-mapping, persist

I am having an issue with a hibernate mapper while trying to store items within the database
I am trying to persist a Booking object

I am trying to store an element with a many to one relationship 
with an element that already has a many to one relationship with another

Booking class has a many to one relationship with the Event class but the Event Class already has a many to one relationship with the Users Class
Which I am also trying to save again within the same table

```
Booking{
  //many to one
  Users(owner)
  //many to one
  Users(user)
  //many to one
  Event(venue)
}

Event{
  //many to one
  Users(owner)
}

Users{

}
```

Booking.hbm.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="" table="booking" catalog="eventer">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="capacity" type="string">
            <column name="capacity" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="date" type="string">
            <column name="date" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="eventname" type="string">
            <column name="eventname" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="venue" class="entities.Event" cascade="all">
            <meta attribute="class-description" inherit="false">class containing product details</meta>
            <column name="venue" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="owner" class="entities.Users" cascade="all">
            <meta attribute="class-description" inherit="false">class containing product details</meta>
            <column name="owner" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="pricing" type="int">
            <column name="pricing" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="entities.Users" cascade="all">
            <meta attribute="class-description" inherit="false">class containing product details</meta>
            <column name="users" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Booking.java

```java
package entities;
// Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1



/**
 * Booking generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Booking  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String capacity;
     private String date;
     private String eventname;
     private Event venue;
     private Users owner;
     private int pricing;
     private Users user;

    public Booking() {
    }


    public Booking(String capacity, String date, String eventname, int pricing) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.date = date;
        this.eventname = eventname;
        this.pricing = pricing;
    }
    public Booking(String capacity, String date, String eventname, Event venue, Users owner, int pricing, Users user) {
       this.capacity = capacity;
       this.date = date;
       this.eventname = eventname;
       this.venue = venue;
       this.owner = owner;
       this.pricing = pricing;
       this.user = user;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCapacity() {
        return this.capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(String capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getEventname() {
        return this.eventname;
    }

    public void setEventname(String eventname) {
        this.eventname = eventname;
    }
    public Event getVenue() {
        return this.venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(Event venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }
    public Users getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Users owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public int getPricing() {
        return this.pricing;
    }

    public void setPricing(int pricing) {
        this.pricing = pricing;
    }
    public Users getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }




}
```

Event.hbm.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entities.Event" table="event" catalog="eventer">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="image" type="string">
            <column name="image" length="10000" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="location" type="string">
            <column name="location" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="upto100" type="int">
            <column name="upto100" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="upto300" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="upto300" />
        </property>
        <property name="upto500" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="upto500" />
        </property>
        <property name="upto1000" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="upto1000" />
        </property>
        <property name="phoneno" type="int">
            <column name="phoneno" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="scenario" type="string">
            <column name="scenario" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="mail" type="string">
            <column name="mail" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="owner" class="entities.Users" cascade="all">
            <meta attribute="class-description" inherit="false">class containing product details</meta>
            <column name="owner" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="description" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Event.java

```java
package entities;
// Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;




/**
 * Event generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Event  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String image;
     private String location;
     private int upto100;
     private Integer upto300;
     private Integer upto500;
     private Integer upto1000;
     private int phoneno;
     private String scenario;
     private String name;
     private String mail;
     private Users owner;
     private String description;

    public Event() {
    }


    public Event(String image, String location, int upto100, int phoneno, String scenario, String name, String mail) {
        this.image = image;
        this.location = location;
        this.upto100 = upto100;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
        this.scenario = scenario;
        this.name = name;
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    public Event(String image, String location, int upto100, Integer upto300, Integer upto500, Integer upto1000, int phoneno, String scenario, String name, String mail, Users owner, String description) {
       this.image = image;
       this.location = location;
       this.upto100 = upto100;
       this.upto300 = upto300;
       this.upto500 = upto500;
       this.upto1000 = upto1000;
       this.phoneno = phoneno;
       this.scenario = scenario;
       this.name = name;
       this.mail = mail;
       this.owner = owner;
       this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public int getUpto100() {
        return this.upto100;
    }

    public void setUpto100(int upto100) {
        this.upto100 = upto100;
    }
    public Integer getUpto300() {
        return this.upto300;
    }

    public void setUpto300(Integer upto300) {
        this.upto300 = upto300;
    }
    public Integer getUpto500() {
        return this.upto500;
    }

    public void setUpto500(Integer upto500) {
        this.upto500 = upto500;
    }
    public Integer getUpto1000() {
        return this.upto1000;
    }

    public void setUpto1000(Integer upto1000) {
        this.upto1000 = upto1000;
    }
    public int getPhoneno() {
        return this.phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }
    public String getScenario() {
        return this.scenario;
    }

    public void setScenario(String scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getMail() {
        return this.mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
    public Users getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Users owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /*public String toStreng(Event event) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(event);
    }

    public Event fromStreng(String string) throws IOException {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(string, Event.class);
    }*/


}
```

Users.hbm.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entities.Users" table="users" catalog="eventer">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="image" type="string">
            <column name="image" length="1000" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="username" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstname" type="string">
            <column name="firstname" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastname" type="string">
            <column name="lastname" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="phoneno" type="int">
            <column name="phoneno" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="gender" type="string">
            <column name="gender" length="10" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Users.java

```java
package entities;
// Generated Jul 23, 2019 11:11:55 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1



/**
 * Users generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Users  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer id;
     private String image;
     private String email;
     private String username;
     private String password;
     private String firstname;
     private String lastname;
     private int phoneno;
     private String gender;

    public Users() {
    }


    public Users(String email, String username, String password, String firstname, String lastname, int phoneno, String gender) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public Users(String image, String email, String username, String password, String firstname, String lastname, int phoneno, String gender) {
       this.image = image;
       this.email = email;
       this.username = username;
       this.password = password;
       this.firstname = firstname;
       this.lastname = lastname;
       this.phoneno = phoneno;
       this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return this.firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return this.lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public int getPhoneno() {
        return this.phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(int phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }




}
```

Comment: *detached entity passed to persist: entities.Event*. Add the exception output. `I am trying to store an element with a many to one relationship with an element that already has a many to one relationship with another`. So you are trying to save an instance of which object? You will also need to add the code that constructs and attempts to save this instance.

Comment: Booking class has a many to one relationship with the Event class but the Event Class already has a many to one relationship with the Users Class

Comment: Which I am also trying to save again within the same table    
Booking{
Users(owner)
Users(user)
Event(venue)
}

Comment: You should update your question with the pertinent information rather than adding it in the comments.

Comment: I have updated it